# Not Receive more than one data from arduino through bluetooth in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, bluetooth, arduino

I have Arduino Uno R3 with Wireless Proto Shield and I want to communicate with Windows Phone 8.

I am using the base from the example [Windows_Phone_8_communicating_with_Arduino_using_Bluetooth](http://katastrophos.net/nokia-wiki/www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Windows_Phone_8_communicating_with_Arduino_using_Bluetooth.html)

This is an asynchronous receiving method:

```
private async void ReceiveMessages(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {

                // Read first byte (length of the subsequent message, 255 or less). 
                uint sizeFieldCount = await dataReader.LoadAsync(1);
                if (sizeFieldCount != 1)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data. 
                    return;
                }

                // Read the message. 
                uint messageLength = dataReader.ReadByte();
                uint actualMessageLength = await dataReader.LoadAsync(messageLength);
                if (messageLength != actualMessageLength)
                {
                    // The underlying socket was closed before we were able to read the whole data. 
                    return;
                }
                // Read the message and process it.
                string message = dataReader.ReadString(actualMessageLength);
                MessageReceived(message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

I have some methods that sends me back info from the Arduino, (SendCarId, SendRideId)

If I try to send each of this commands by itself it will send me back (from the Arduino) the right data.

But when I send the requests one after other it only response to the first and not to the second. (it never get the second time to the method ReceiveMessages )

Anyone have idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that if I terminate the connection when I get answer, 
I can then initialize new connection (maybe not the most effective solution but it's working)

```
  public void Terminate()
    {
        connected = false;

        dataReadWorker.DoWork -= new DoWorkEventHandler(ReceiveMessages);

        if (socket != null)
        {
            socket.Dispose();
            socket = null;
        }
        if (dataReadWorker != null)
        {
            dataReadWorker.CancelAsync();

        }
    }


public void Initialize()
    {
        socket = new StreamSocket();
        dataReadWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        dataReadWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        dataReadWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(ReceiveMessages);
    }
```